# border-top color is not being passed into this div

Tags: css

**Intent**
To get a red border-top at the footer

---

I have a footer that has the following CSS rules

```
#footer 
{
  text-align: left;
  background: url("/assets/img/template/wild_oliva_dark.png") repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
  background-position: center;
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

In Firebug I was testing style changes and the border top does not seem to get passed in

```
#footer 
  { 
    border-top: 3px solid #b13535; 
  }
```

I test similar CSS into this test [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JGallardo/92HPL/) and it works just fine.

I have a page deployed to this [test page](http://windev.jgallardo.me/pages/video-bruxzir-zirconia-dental-crown/index.aspx)

Comment: rgb(0, 0, 0) is black, not red.  not related to your problem though.

Comment: @andi, yes that is what is current. But I was testing different colors in firebug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The footer has a class "block" applied to it, which sets the `display` property to `table-row`. Table rows cannot have borders.